# Units of Work required to create a dynamically growing array

Tags: java

The project I am working on requires me to create an array that will grow when data is added (not worried about shrinking right now) by adding 50 to the array length when data is added over the cap.

It starts with a capacity of 100. So, for example, at the 101st add, it expands to a capacity of 150.

Before I begin, I need to consider how many units of work are required to make the array grow, for say 1000 items, assuming it takes one unit of work to write an item into an array location, and one unit of work to allocate a new array.

My thought process was that it takes:
Arr Length   Units of Work
100          1+100+50
150          1+200
...

Thinking that 1 is for allocation, 50 is for filling the array, and the middle term for copying the data over. Therefore 1000 would require 10367.

Does that sound right?

Comment: Why are you implementing this yourself? Use an `ArrayList` or a `LinkedList`.

Comment: @BoristheSpider looks like a homework exercise

Comment: @LuiggiMendoza then it should be labelled as such.

Comment: @BoristheSpider Not into reading titles are we ? It's pretty clearly labeled as homework :/

Comment: @gbtimmon not looking at the edit history are we? The `homework` was added _after_ my comment.

Comment: I added that after, sorry

Comment: @user2844289 that's perfectly alright, welcome to StackOverflow. Don't forget to accept an answer if it's correct.

Answer (score 2):

If it takes 1 unit of work to create a new array, and 1 unit per item written to the array, then it will take

```
(1 + 100) // initial create and fill
+ (1 + 150)
...
+ (1 + 1000)
```

Which is 10469

Comment: I did the math again and I got the same thing as you. I must have messed something up. Thanks